# How to create route for static pages in laravel 4

Tags: laravel, laravel-routing

I have a page in the database. I want to have a URL like `mysite.com/page_alias` for the page.
 How do I properly write route in laravel 4.
In kohana i did this:

```
Route::set('static', '<page>', array('page' => "page|page2|page3|etc"))
        ->defaults(array(
            'action' => 'index',
            'controller' => 'Static',
            'directory' => 'Index',
        ));
```

Thanks.
Sorry for my english.

Comment: If you share your Laravel code, would be easier for us to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never use Kohana but looking at its doc, if I'm right, this is the closest way to do what you used to do with Kohana.

```
Route::get('{page}', 'StaticController@index')->where('page', 'page|page2|page3|etc');
```

PS: take a look at this http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/routing (you probably have already checked the doc but in case..)